# The smallest eigenvalue of an infinite sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose every entry lies in $[-1/2, 1/2]$. Let $B$ be defined via the infinite sum,
$$B = A + D A D + D^2 A D^2 + D^3 A D^3 +\cdots$$
Can I upper bound the smallest eigenvalue of $B$ in terms of the smallest eigenvalue of $A$?

Motivation: in my case, $A$ is very close to being singular, and I want to argue that $B$ is close to being singular as well. It seems like the diagonal matrix should not alter things much since its entries are between $-1/2$ and $1/2$.

The difficulty is that it is not true that $\lambda_{\rm min}(X + Y) \leq \lambda_{\rm min}(X) + \lambda_{\rm min}(Y)$ for two pd matrices $X,Y$.

Comment: Can you explicitly write the components Of the sum?

Comment: Using geometric progressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A$ being close to singular does not make $B$ close to singular. For example, for $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$,

$$
B=\pmatrix{\frac1{1-d_1^2}&\frac1{1-d_1d_2}\\\frac1{1-d_1d_2}&\frac1{1-d_2^2}}\;,
$$

and this need not be singular, e.g. for $d_1=\frac12$, $d_2=-\frac12$ we have $B=\pmatrix{\frac43&\frac45\\\frac45&\frac43}$.